# How to solve system of equations with fractions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have this equation

$U=\frac{a_0+a_1X+a_2Y}{1+c_1X+c_2Y}$
$V=\frac{b_0+b_1X+b_2Y}{1+c_1X+c_2Y}$

Where (X,Y) is a point on a quadrilateral and (U,V) is a point on a rectangle, and (X,Y) actually maps to (U,V) with perspective transformation. From http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf. (2nd last page)

I am trying to solve for these coefficients but I don't understand how. I know I can sub in the 4 corner coordinates of the quadrilateral corners (which I know), and U,V is the corresponding corner on the rectangle (which I also know). This would give me 8 equations. But then I don't know how to solve for the 5 unknowns. If this was a linear system of equations, then I can do it with Gaussian elimination but for this, does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of 4 pairs of corners $\{ (X_i , Y_i), (U_i , V_i) \}_{i=1}^{4}$, as you said, that you know and can plug into the two given equations to solve for the coefficients. You will have 8 equations and 8 unknowns.

The equations can be quite easily manipulated into a linear form,
\begin{align*}
U = \frac{a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 Y}{1 + c_1 X + c_2 Y} &\iff \left(1 + c_1 X + c_2 Y \right)U = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 Y
\\ &\iff a_0 + Xa_1 + Ya_2 - XUc_1 - YUc_2 = U
\\ &\iff a_0 + Xa_1 + Ya_2 + 0\cdot b_0 + 0\cdot b_1 + 0\cdot b_2 - XUc_1 - YUc_2 = U
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
V = \frac{b_0 + b_1 X + b_2 Y}{1 + c_1 X + c_2 Y} &\iff \left(1 + c_1 X + c_2 Y \right)V = b_0 + b_1 X + b_2 Y
\\ &\iff b_0 + Xb_1 + Yb_2 - XVc_1 - YVc_2 = V
\\ &\iff 0\cdot a_0 + 0\cdot a_1 + 0\cdot a_2 + b_0 + Xb_1 + Yb_2 - XVc_1 - YVc_2 = V
\end{align*}
And with these you can use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Do I have to solve it all at once with 8 unknowns or can I break this into two systems?

Comment: Each formula produces 4 equations which contain 5 unknowns ($c_1$ and $c_2$ are shared). You won't be able to solve the systems separately (in general), but it might reduce them to simpler forms.

Comment: What do u mean reduce to simpler form?

Comment: You might get cancellation of some terms and be able to express your system of equations in a reduced form, possibly even solve for some of the coefficients completely.

Comment: Do u mean with Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Yes. This page has an example of Gaussian elimination for an underdetermined system: http://www.math.fsu.edu/~fusaro/EngMath/Ch6/SSG.html